# Change option value into href?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I downloaded some html template which I am trying to readjust and I have some code form like this, is it possible that I can change the option "value" into "href" so when client select lets say "Standard Access" and click on the button Buy Now to redirect to the paypal lets say? 
Here is the code :

```
 <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="POST" action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="your-name" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="your-email" placeholder="Your Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="ticket-type" name="ticket-type" class="form-control" >
                <option value="">-- Select Your Ticket Type --</option>
                <option value="standard-access">Standard Access</option>
                <option value="pro-access">Pro Access</option>
                <option value="premium-access">Premium Access</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have some example. Probably it's possible to make it better, but I don't know the context.

```js
$('#confirmButton').on('click', function() {
  const href = $('#redirect').val();
  window.location.href = href;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="redirect">
  <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select Your Ticket Type --</option>
  <option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="confirmButton">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Why use jQuery?

Comment: @QuentinVeron Template he provided is Bootstrap based, so he has to use jQuery anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can add onsubmit listener to your form.

```
<form method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="myFunction()">...
</form>

<script>
myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("ticket-type").value;
    if (x== 'standard-access') {window.location.href = "http://www.URL1.html";}
    else if (x== 'pro-access') {window.location.href = "http://www.URL2.html";}
    return false; // to prevent default submit
}
</script>
```